# How to insert a column's values into an SQL where statement using VBA

Tags: mysql, vba

I have a list of account ID in column A. The range of that column is dynamic. How do I write a module that will take those values and use them in an SQL IN statement. Below is my attempt at doing this. I pieced together multiple scripts I found so sorry if it is a mess.

```
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim wbBook As Workbook
    Dim wsSheet As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim sl As Long
    
With wsSheet
lastrow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
End With

' Appending the values to a single variable

For i = 1 To lastrow
  s1 = s1 & "'" & Val(wsSheet.Cells(i, 1)) & "'" & ","
Next



' Variable which could be used in  IN command

    If lastrow > 0 Then
        s1 = Mid(s1, 1, Len(s1) - 1)
        s1 = "(" & s1 & ")"
    Else
         Exit Sub
    End If

'    ' Create the connection string.
    sConnString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; Server=snapshot;" & _
                  "Database=salesforce_replica;" & _
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    ' Create the Connection and Recordset objects.
    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

    ' Open the connection and execute.
    conn.Open sConnString
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.account where Account_ID_18__c = " & s1;)

    ' Check we have data.
    If Not rs.EOF Then
        ' Transfer result.
        Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    ' Close the recordset
        rs.Close
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If

    ' Clean up
    If CBool(conn.State And adStateOpen) Then conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing
    Set rs = Nothing

End Sub
```

My goal is to figure out how to take a dynamic range of values and use them within an SQL Where statement.

Comment: How many distinct values are in the list?  Your SQL is using `=` where it should have `IN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```vb
Sub ConnectSqlServer()

    Dim conn As ADODB.Connection, rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim sConnString As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rngIds As Range, sql As String, inList As String
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets("list")
    Set rngIds = ws.Range("A1:A" & ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row)
    inList = InClause(rngIds)
    If Len(inList) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "No id values!"
        Exit Sub   'nothing to query...
    End If
      
    sConnString = "Driver={ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server}; Server=snapshot;" & _
                  "Database=salesforce_replica;" & _
                  "Trusted_Connection=yes;"

    Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
    conn.Open sConnString
    
    Set rs = conn.Execute("SELECT * FROM dbo.account where Account_ID_18__c in " & inList)

    If Not rs.EOF Then
        wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rs
    Else
        MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
    End If
    
    rs.Close
    conn.Close
    
End Sub

'Generate a SQL "in" list from distinct values in range `rng`
'  Add single quotes around values unless `IsNumeric` is True
'  Note if `rng` has too many values you may exceed your max. SQL query size!
Function InClause(rng As Range, Optional IsNumeric As Boolean = False) As String
    Dim c As Range, dict As Object, arr, qt As String, v
    Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    For Each c In rng.Cells
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then dict(v) = 1
    Next c
    If Not IsNumeric Then qt = "'"
    If dict.Count > 0 Then
        InClause = "(" & qt & Join(dict.keys, qt & "," & qt) & qt & ")"
    End If
End Function
```